# Detect which file uses console.log?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, console.log

I am running WordPress with my ownchild theme which also includes redux framework for admin option.

When I have a look in the javascript console in chrome, I seem to be getting a phantom console.log. For every option I change in my option panel, it's being output in the console. I went through several files that I thought would cause that, but I can't find the console.log() which seems to be responsible for that.

Is there anyway to find out what file and what line is responsible for that phantom log?

Comment: Every `console.log` message have the filename + line on the right where it was invoked from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your dev tools in chrome and open up sources. Search for console with Ctrl+Shift+F (Cmd+Option+F on mac)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Funny enough it showed me the console.log which I commented out several hours back and which I thought would be responsible for it. It seems chrome does heavy caching on .js files. Doing hardreload and clearing the cache in chrome solved it. Never thought that chrome would cache for hours and hours a file that I have been constantly modifying with big changes.